# Creating a table in "MSWord" document out of a text in a .txt file

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

In the following file "E:\my_folder\my_future_table.txt" I have this text:

```
#   animal  country
1   rabbit  Germany
2   wolf    France
3   koala   USA
```

(please note that all the words in each line of that text are separated by tabs)

What VBS script do I need to use in order to create a "Word" file (.doc) with a table created on the basis of that text? (In this example, the table should have 3 columns and 4 rows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this with a healthy degree of credit to [the Scripting Guy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692897.aspx)

1. The vbs reads the test file (pls change your path), and then splits it by line break into an array `ArrVar`
2. Each line in this array is split further by `VbTab` into a second array, `ArrVar2`
3. The vbs creates a word table equal in size to the length of `ArrVar` and width of `ArrVar2`
4. Each item is written to the table cell by cell, row by row

[image: output]

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()

Set objRange = objDoc.Range()
strFilePath = "c:\temp\my_future_table.txt"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objTF = objFSO.opentextfile(strFilePath)
strAll = objTF.readall
arrVar = Split(strAll, vbNewLine)
numcols = UBound(Split(arrVar(0), vbTab)) + 1

objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, UBound(arrVar) - LBound(arrVar) + 1, numcols
Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)

For lngrow = LBound(arrVar) To UBound(arrVar)
    arrVar2 = Split(arrVar(lngrow), vbTab)
    For lngcol = LBound(arrVar2) To UBound(arrVar2)
     objTable.Cell(lngrow + 1, lngcol + 1).Range.Text = arrVar2(lngcol)
    Next
Next

objTF.Close
set objFSO = Nothing

objTable.AutoFormat (9)
objWord.Visible = True
```