# Inserting a table into Outlook email using VBScript

Tags: email, vbscript, outlook, ms-word

I have a table in a Microsoft Word document that I want to insert into the middle of a message in an Outlook email. When I manually copy the table into an email draft, it preserves the formatting, but when I don't, the formatting changes into a list-style. For example, this is what the table would look like:

9898    Apple   color

1394    Banana  blue

with borders, but in the email that gets sent, it shows up as

9898

Apple

Color

1394

Banana

Blue

I had to add in extra lines above because Stack Overflow wasn't showing it as each element on an separate line.

Within my code, I've taken the table and concatenated it within the string that forms the message of the email. I think this may be the problem, but I'm not sure how to change this to separately include the table. Here is my code:

```
message = "Dear " & owner & ", " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
message = message & "Here is the data we have: " & vbCrLf
message = message & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & textToTable(fileName, file)
message = message & "Can you please email us back with the updated data?"
message = message & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Thank you."  

Set MyItem = ol.CreateItem(0)
With MyItem
    .To = me
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Table"
    .BodyFormat = 3
    .Body = message
    .Send
End With
```

I used a lot of the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868928/vbs-creating-a-table-in-msword-document-out-of-a-text-in-a-txt-file) in my textToTable function, which seems to work as intended. The only problem is getting Outlook to preserve formatting of the table; does anyone have any suggestions as to how to do this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the plain text Body property. Create an HTML table and assign the HTMLBody property to a property formatted HTML string.